# Three.js - Load Textures from ZIP File and Parse to GLTF

Tags: javascript, three.js, zip, gltf

Suppose someone selects a `.zip` file (`<input type="file">`) with the following content:

```
3d-model.zip
    |- 3d-model.obj
    |- 3d-model.mtl
    |- texture1.jpg
    |- texture2.jpg
```

---

#### Here are some methods I tried

✔️ means that it worked

✖️ means that it didn't work

---

### ✔️ #1 Mesh-only

```
const objBlob = await createBlob(zipfiles['3d-model.obj'])
const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(objBlob)
const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader()
objLoader.load(objUrl, obj => {

    // mesh is displayed correctly
    scence.add(obj)

    const gltfExporter = new GLTFExporter()
    // parsing works fine
    gltfExporter.parse(obj, result => {
        const output = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
        const blob = new Blob([output], { type: 'text/plain' }, `3d-model.gltf`)
    })

})
```

---

### ✔️ #2 Mesh with simple material

```
# 3d-model.mtl file

newmtl material1
Kd 0 1 0

newmtl material2
Kd 1 0 0

const objBlob = await createBlob(zipfiles['3d-model.obj'])
const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(objBlob)

const mtlBlob = await createBlob(zipfiles['3d-model.mtl'])
const mtlUrl = URL.createObjectURL(mtlBlob)

const mtlLoaer = new THREE.MTLLoader()
mtlLoader.load(mtlUrl, mtl => {
    const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader()
    objLoader.setMaterials(mtl)
    objLoader.load(objUrl, obj => {

        // mesh is displayed correctly
        scence.add(obj)

        // parsing works fine
        const gltfExporter = new GLTFExporter()
        gltfExporter.parse(obj, result => {
            const output = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
            const blob = new Blob([output], { type: 'text/plain' }, `3d-model.gltf`)
        })

    })
})
```

---

### ✖️ #3 Mesh + material with texture maps

```
# 3d-model.mtl file

newmtl material1
map_Kd texture1.jpg

newmtl material2
map_Kd texture2.jpg

const objBlob = await createBlob(zipfiles['3d-model.obj'])
const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(objBlob)

const mtlBlob = await createBlob(zipfiles['3d-model.mtl'])
const mtlUrl = URL.createObjectURL(mtlBlob)

const mtlLoaer = new THREE.MTLLoader()
mtlLoader.load(mtlUrl, mtl => {
    const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader()
    objLoader.setMaterials(mtl)
    objLoader.load(objUrl, obj => {

        // error while adding mesh (see screenshot below)
        scence.add(obj)

        // parsing throws error (see screenshot below)
        const gltfExporter = new GLTFExporter()
        gltfExporter.parse(obj, result => {
            const output = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
            const blob = new Blob([output], { type: 'text/plain' }, `3d-model.gltf`)
        })

    })
})
```

I get some errors, which makes total sense (because those textures do not exist at this location)

Error while adding mesh to the scene
[image: error while adding mesh to the scene]

Error while parsing to GLTF
[image: error while parsing to gltf]
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/398c4f39ebdb8b23eefd4a7a5ec49ec0c96c7462/examples/jsm/exporters/GLTFExporter.js#L778

---

### ✖️ #4 So, I tried the following

```
# 3d-model.mtl file

newmtl material1
map_Kd texture1.jpg

newmtl material2
map_Kd texture2.jpg

const objBlob = await createBlob(zipfiles['3d-model.obj'])
const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(objBlob)

const texture1Blob = await createBlob(zipfiles['texture1.jpg'])
const texture1Url = URL.createObjectURL(texture1Blob)
const texture2Blob = await createBlob(zipfiles['texture2.jpg'])
const texture2Url = URL.createObjectURL(texture2Blob)

const mtlFileContent = `
newmtl material1
map_Kd ${texture1Url}

newmtl material2
map_Kd ${texture2Url}
`
const mtlBlob = new Blob([mtlFileContent])
const mtlUrl = URL.createObjectURL(mtlBlob)

const mtlLoaer = new THREE.MTLLoader()
mtlLoader.load(mtlUrl, mtl => {
    const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader()
    objLoader.setMaterials(mtl)
    objLoader.load(objUrl, obj => {

        // adding the object to the scence works fine (with materials and textures)
        scence.add(obj)

        // but parsing throws error (see screenshot below)
        const gltfExporter = new GLTFExporter()
        gltfExporter.parse(obj, result => {
            const output = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
            const blob = new Blob([output], { type: 'text/plain' }, `3d-model.gltf`)
        })
    })
})
```

With this method, the object is added to the Three.js scene with materials and textures. Awesome! **But the `GLTFExporter` still isn't happy:**

Error while parsing to GLTF
[image: error while parsing to gltf]
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/398c4f39ebdb8b23eefd4a7a5ec49ec0c96c7462/examples/jsm/exporters/GLTFExporter.js#L778

It seems like the `GLTFExporter` cant fetch blob URLs?!

---

Do I need to rewrite the `GLTFExporter` to support "blob URLs" or is there another way to load the textures from a zip file?